# Unable to receive datagram over the internet

Tags: java, android, networking

I have a UDP client sending packets to my UDP server.

The packets are sent and received successfully when I use the server's IP address or the when I use the router's public IP address

```
// Works
Constants.SERVER_IP_ADDRESS

// Works
Constants.PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS;
```

However, I'm not able to receive any packet when sending over the internet even though I've set up forwarding.

Any idea why? Thanks.

`UdpClient`

```
public class UdpClient {

    private String mServerAddress = Constants.PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS;
    private int mServerPort = Constants.PORT;
    private static final int MAX_TRIES = 5;

    public void sendDatagramPacket(){

        // Cannot network on Main UI thread
        new AsyncTask(){
            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {

                System.out.println("sendDatagramPacket");

                // Create a socket
                DatagramSocket socket = null;
                try{socket = new DatagramSocket();}
                catch (SocketException e){e.printStackTrace();}

                // Create a datagram
                byte[] bytesToSend = new byte[3];
                bytesToSend[0] = (byte) 255;
                bytesToSend[1] = (byte) 255;
                bytesToSend[2] = (byte) 255;

                InetAddress serverInetAddress = null;
                try{serverInetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(mServerAddress);}
                catch (UnknownHostException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

                DatagramPacket datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(
                        bytesToSend, bytesToSend.length, serverInetAddress, mServerPort);

                // Send packet; packets may be lost, so we have to keep trying
                int tries = 0;
                while(tries < MAX_TRIES) {
                    try{socket.send(datagramPacket);}
                    catch (NullPointerException e){e.printStackTrace();}
                    catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
                    tries++;
                }

                try{socket.close();}
                catch (NullPointerException e){e.printStackTrace();}

                return null;
            }
        }.execute();
    }
}
```

`UdpServer`

```
public class UdpServer {

    private int mHostPort = Constants.MAC_PORT;

    // Defines max receive-buffer size; maximum possible for UDP is ~64,000
    private static final int MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 256;

    public void listenForPacket(){

        System.out.println("listenForPacket");

        new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run(){

                // Get the socket to the receiving port
                DatagramSocket socket = null;
                try { socket = new DatagramSocket(mHostPort);}
                catch (SocketException e){e.printStackTrace();}

                // Create receive-buffer and receive-packet
                byte[] receiveBuffer = new byte[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
                DatagramPacket datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveBuffer,MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);

                // Pause thread here listening for packet
                try{
                    socket.receive(datagramPacket);
                    System.out.println("Datagram received successfully");
                }
                catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}



                try{socket.close();}
                catch (NullPointerException e){e.printStackTrace();}
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Related perhaps?: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching You may want to check your router capabilities.

Comment: This probably belongs on ServerFault.  It is almost certainly a problem with firewalls and / or NAT; i.e. network configuration.  That's not a programming problem.

Comment: The only programming issue is that your handling of exceptions leaves a lot to be desired.  That is liable to make your code unreliable and "noisy" ... but it is unlikely to (silently) cause the problem you are asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer doesn't directly address your problem, but it **could** do indirectly.  (Your bad exception handling could be *hiding* other problems ...)

You have systemic problems in the way that you deal with exceptions.  For example:

```
    DatagramSocket socket = null;
    try { socket = new DatagramSocket(mHostPort);}
    catch (SocketException e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

What happens if an exception is thrown by the constructor?

Answer: you print a stack trace, and then keep going as if nothing bad happened.

Except that something bad *did* happen.  Indeed, if the constructor failed, and you don't have a `DatagramSocket`, then the remaining code cannot *possibly* work.  But you "recovered".

This pattern is repeated in a number of places.  Indeed you end up with code to catch NPEs that are directly *caused* by incorrect "recovery" code.

This the right way to do it:

```
public void run() {
    try (DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(mHostPort)) { 

        // Get the socket to the receiving port
        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(mHostPort);

        // Create receive-buffer and receive-packet
        byte[] receiveBuffer = new byte[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
        DatagramPacket datagramPacket = 
             new DatagramPacket(receiveBuffer,MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);

        // Pause thread here listening for packet
        socket.receive(datagramPacket);
        System.out.println("Datagram received successfully");
    }
    catch (IOException | RuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Things to note:

- As well as being more correct (I claim), this code is actually *simpler* than your version.  There are fewer error cases, and (I claim) the source of those pesky NPE's has been eliminated.
- The exception handling does not attempt to recover.  If an exception occurs, the thread will end ... immediately
- Note the use of try-with-resources to ensure that the socket is *always* closed.
- Catching `RuntimeException` is probably unnecessary ... see above about NPEs.
- An alternative to handling the exception in the `run()` method would be to use a default exception handler.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! It worked! I can't understand why though, since wouldn't an exception thrown in my version also be thrown in your version? I didn't see any exceptions in the log.

Comment: Ah ... yes ... but you didn't say anything about what was in the logs  (or not) :-).  And, I am a little surprised that it worked because I couldn't see a specific bug that the exception handling was *definitely* hiding.